# First query string parameter being ignored by Laravel or Wordpress/WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, woocommerce

**Tech stack**

- PHP 7.4.2
- Laravel 7

**Background**

I'm attempting to pull in the active products from our WooCommerce site, one page at a time. These then have required data pulled out and formatted into JSON, and returned to the user (in this case a marketing platform making an API call).

**Issue**

Whichever query parameter is first in my list is getting either removed before it leaves my system, or ignored by the WC/WP REST API.

**Code making the call**

```
    function getProducts($page = 1, $per_page = 100, $status = 'publish') {
        
        $query = array(
            // 't' => 1, // For testing first parameter bug
            'page' => $page,
            'per_page' => $per_page,
            'status' => $status,
        );

        $string = http_build_query($query, null, '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);

        $url = $this->finalUrl . '/wp-json/wc/v3/products?' . $string;

        $json = file_get_contents($url);

        return json_decode($json);
    }
```

If I dump `$url` I get:

`https://user:pass@domain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?page=5&per_page=100&status=publish`

This seems valid as far as I can tell. Putting it into Postman, I get the 5th page of 100 records, as expected. However, if I run it in my system, I get the first page every time.

Then if I swap `page` and `per_page` round, I will get the page I want but only 10 records which is the default, not the 100 I ask for. Then of course if I put status first, I get inactive/archived products too.

Additionally if I change the URL to a Pipedream URL, I can see all 3 parameters clearly being listed.

Lastly, I tested by adding the `t=1` parameter in first as a dummy parameter, and then the rest of the parameters all work fine, and I would get my 5th page of 100 records no problem.

If anyone can assist or point me in the right direction that will be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out in this case, there was a stray letter in a uri rewrite rule on the wordpress site, causing the name of the first parameter to be prepended with said letter.

This was found within `try_files $uri /index.php?uri=$uri&i$args;` rule. Note the `i` before the `$args` being appended.

In my above example, `page` would be renamed `ipage` before it reache the API.

Removed and it now works.